# Malwarebytes full scan loads GUI when done through Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, malwarebytes

I have used the Microsoft Task Scheduler to schedule my Malwarebytes updates and full scan since I can't get the Malwarebytes scheduler to work. The thing that is bothering me is that each time the scan starts, the GUI opens. How can I stop this? I want the scan to run without the GUI open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different suggestions floating around on the internet, in some it mentions `/fullauto`, and in others it mentions `mbam.exe -silent`.

Try these, or see below.

A full list of the usable switches is in the help file, according to this website: http://malwaretips.com/threads/mbam-command-line-parameters.12235/

Comment: Using `-silent` works, but there is one thing that I want: if the scan runs and finds nothing, I don't want to know about it, but if the scan does find something, I want to be alerted when it finishes. Does using `-silent` give me this ability or not?

Comment: `-silent` won't. But you could try running is as `mbam.exe /minimized -terminate` which will run it minimized (something that you may not really want), and terminate the program if no threats are detected. All in all it's hard to say, it's probably best to search in the MBAM Help File for the most up-to-date list of switches.

Answer (score 0):

mbam.exe /parameter
(where parameter is one of the following)

/debug: allows you to collect information to send as a bug report.

/developer: this command line parameter is explained in the false positives section.

/minimized: allows you to start the program minimized.

/quickscan: allows you to run a quick scan.

/quickscanterminate: allows you to run a quick scan. 
                     Program terminates if no items found.

/fullscan: allows you to run a full scan.

/fullscanterminate: allows you to run a full scan. 
                    Program terminates if no items found.

/runupdate: allows you to update the program without displaying result dialogs.

/register: allows you to register the program without displaying main dialog.

/fullauto: allows you to run a full scan silently.

Example: mbam.exe /register 12345 AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD

/updateshowdialog: allows you to update the program displaying all dialogs.

/schedule : allows you to schedule an update and scan for a specific hour. 
            Scan will happen 5 minutes after update.

Comment: These commands are for Malwarebytes v1. Malwarebytes v2 does not support these commands.